# How to reset questionnaire on 'no'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a questionnaire which shows the next question after the previous one is answered. I managed to get this working, but when 'no' is pressed, I want the questionnaire to reset to that answer and erase all later questions so you can start again from that point. At the moment my form goes nuts when I press 'no' and I can't get my head around it. Could someone help me out?

HTML:

```
<p>1. Question 1</p>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" /> Yes</label>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" /> No</label>

<div id="blk-1" style="display:none"><!-- 1. Choice: Yes -->
<p>1. Question 2</p>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio1" type="radio" name="toggler2" value="3" /> Yes</label>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio2" type="radio" name="toggler2" value="4" /> No</label>
</div><!-- /blk-1 -->

<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none"><!-- 1. Choice: No -->
No
</div><!-- /blk-2 -->

<div id="blk-3" style="display:none"><!-- 2. Choice: Yes -->
<p>3. Question 3</p>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio1" type="radio" name="toggler3" value="5" /> Yes</label>
<label><input class="toggler" id="radio2" type="radio" name="toggler3" value="6" /> No</label>
</div><!-- /blk-3 -->

<div id="blk-4" class="toHide" style="display:none"><!-- 2. Choice: No -->
No
</div><!-- /blk-4 -->

<div id="blk-5" class="toHide" style="display:none"><!-- 3. Choice: Yes -->
Yes - End
</div><!-- /blk-4 -->

<div id="blk-6" class="toHide" style="display:none"><!-- 3. Choice: No -->
No - End
</div><!-- /blk-4 -->
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $(".toggler").click(function() {
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).toggle();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ximmo/94Vjn/2/

Comment: **Note:** IDs must be unique.

Comment: I don't really get this part: I want the questionnaire to reset to that answer and erase all later questions so you can start again from that point.

Comment: When you press 'no' on for example the first answer after you filled in all the answers with 'yes', I would like the questionnaire to jump back to the first question and remove the later answers.

Comment: Lazy way would be to refresh the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle, check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Vjn/3/)..

jQuery

```
    $(".toggler").click(function() {
        $('.toHide').hide();

        if($(this).attr("id") == "radio2"){
            var selector = $(this).parents("div").next("div");
            while(selector.length == 1){
                selector.hide();
                selector.find(".toggler").prop("checked",false);
                selector = selector.next("div");
            }
        }
        $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).toggle();
    });
```